# How to connect a DB in Rest Assured , which is currently hosted locally

Tags: java, kubernetes, automation, rest-assured

Currently I have to hit below commands to connect to a DB on my system:
First command

```
gcloud --project lover-dev-kubernetes container clusters get-credentials dev-us-west1-cluster --region us-west1 && kubectl config set-cluster gke_lover-dev-kubernetes_us-west1_dev-us-west1-cluster --server=https://dev-us-west1-ingress-nginx.dev.pdx13.lover.network && kubectl config unset clusters.gke_lover-dev-kubernetes_us-west1_dev-us-west1-cluster.certificate-authority-data
```

Second command

```
kubectl -n growth-api-dev port-forward deployment/growth-api 3306:3306 > /dev/null &
```

Can some one please help, how to connect to this DB from Java. I am very new to Kubernatives.
Github Repo:https://github.com/Pulkit773/RestAssured/blob/main/src/test/java/com/spotify/oauth2/tests/SubmitApp.java

Comment: REST assured is for HTTP services, not mysql databases. You'd use JDBC for that

Comment: yes, but i have to hit the db to get the sql results. And with jdbc I am not sure how to hit this db. Because this db will be connected once these commands will run only.